# Stuck at grub rescue prompt after terminating a windows installation

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I recently began the installation process of windows 7 on my Ubuntu machine. When I got to the format option on the Windows OS install prompts, I remembered I had some files on my Ubuntu OS that I wanted to save.

I **aborted** the windows installation process at the stage where it says that I have an incompatible file system.

Here is a link to my boot info:
[boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16518079)